# How to read a single value from appsettings.json containing collections

Tags: c#, appsettings

How can I read the URL value from the below shown appsettings.json file, ***without creating a class to load values through DI***?

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:1234"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried the below snippet but it gives null.

```cs
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

IConfiguration _configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
// 1st attempt
var url = _configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetChildren().First()["Args::serverUrl"];
// 2nd attempt
var url = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Serilog:WriteTo:Args::serverUrl");
// 3rd attempt
var url = _configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetChildren().First().GetSection("Args").GetValue("serverUrl");
```

None of those attempts worked.

There are some existing similar questions but none of them deal with getting a single value from collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry im not really familiar with "those words". English isn't my first language.

This here is your corrected 2nd try, without any dependencys/classes:

```
var configurationBuilder2 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

IConfiguration _configuration2 = configurationBuilder2.Build();


var url2 = _configuration2.GetValue<string>("Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:serverUrl");
```

You just had a little typo thus not accessing the key right.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get an item of an array in the configuration by setting the index. If you have only one item simply you can address it like this:

```cs
var url = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:serverUrl");
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct but the other person beat you to it by 20 minutes.